# Can't restart iPhone OpenGL graphics when I switch back from a UIKit view controller

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es

I'm switching between two iPhone view controllers: A initial viewController running an OpenGL view of a 3D animation, and a second viewController with a UIKit view of program settings. The OpenGL animation runs fine when I start the app, and I can switch to the second VC to alter program settings.  When I switch back from the settings VC via a delegate, I cannot get the OpenGL animation to restart -- I'm only getting a black view.

Is there anything else I need to do to re-initialize the OpenGL-ES state when I switch back to the GL view?

My switch from the GL viewController to the settings viewController works fine:

```
- (IBAction) switchToSettingsView:(id) sender {
    SettingsViewController *controller = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil];
    controller.settingsDelegate = self;
    [self stopTimer];    // Stop the animation
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
}
```

When I return from from the settings view via the following delegate, I see only a black background:

```
- (void) settingsViewControllerDidFinish:(SettingsViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self startTimer];
    [glView startAnimation];
    [glView drawView];   // Explicitly re-drawing the GL view doesn't help
}
```

Adding viewDidAppear/viewWillDisappear did not help.  They do get called as expected.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [glView startAnimation];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [glView stopAnimation];
}
```

I am currently not using CADisplayLink in startAnimation, I'm using an NSTimer.

My OpenGL drawView is running in the GL view after I return via the delegate, but nothing appears on the display.

**UPDATE: RESOLVED!!!**  As quixoto suggested, recreating the EAGL context helped.  I also had to recreate the framebuffers.  Doing either one without the other didn't fix the problem.  Here's the code I used to re-initialize the graphics state:

```
// Re-initialize the EAGL context and framebuffers
- (void)reInitContext {
    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

    eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
        kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

    [context release];      // Releases the old EAGL Context
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

    if (!context) {
        NSLog(@"RECREATING EAGL CONTEXT FAILED!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"RECREATING EAGL CONTEXT SUCCEEDED!");
    };
    if (![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
        NSLog(@"RE-SETTING EAGL CONTEXT FAILED!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"RE-SETTING EAGL CONTEXT SUCCEEDED!");
    };

    [self destroyFramebuffer];
    [self createFramebuffer];

}
```

Comment: Have you made your EAGL context current again when you switch back? Does it work if your transition is not animated, and you start back up afterwards?

Comment: The value of the current context isn't changed when I get back.  I'll try re-initializing the context completely after I get back from the UIKit view, and post an update.

Comment: Thanks @quixoto for an important clue to the resolution. In addition to re-creating the EAGL context, I also had to re-create the framebuffers.